# How to add 1 to each value in an array (in Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here's the prompt:
Loop through an integer array adding one to each element. Return the resulting array. The array may be of any length including 0.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public int[] add1toEach(int[] nums) {
  int[] array = new int[nums.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    nums[i]++;
  }
  return array;
}
```

It works with `add1toEach[]` and `add1toEach[-1]` but that's it. How do I get it to spit out `[7, 7, 3]` if `add1toEach[6, 6, 2]` is the input?

Comment: Your description is quite unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You're creating a new array, updating the original array, but returning the unchanged new array (which will be an array of zeros with the same length as the original array)

Comment: Please explain in plain English what each of the lines of code you've written does. I think you'll see the problem as you are doing that.

Comment: Its because you increment the elements in the nums array but you return a different unused array

Comment: Java 8+ `return Arrays.stream(nums).map(i -> i + 1).toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that you aren't assigning the new added result to the array, nor are you adding it properly.

The proper code is:

```
    public static int[] add1toEach(int[] nums) {
        int[] array = new int[nums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
          array[i]=nums[i]+1;
         }
        return array;
    }
```

What's happening here is that we add 1 to the item, then we assign the item to an identical array, but which the items are all empty. This happens to every single item of the array, as demonstrated in the statement in the for loop `i < nums.length; i++`.

This working example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
      int[] newnums = add1toEach(nums);
      for(int i = 0; i < newnums.length; i++){
          System.out.println(newnums[i]);
      }
    }
    public static int[] add1toEach(int[] nums) {
        int[] array = new int[nums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
          array[i]=nums[i]+1;
         }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Produces

```
2
3
4
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're code doing is it only returns the untouched `int[] array`.

Since you have set the length of your array, you just need to set values to your array with position `array[i]` to make the values assigned and intact position.

```
array[i]=nums[i]++;
```

Comment: This will also modify nums. Thus, that code would appear to work at casual glance, but is in fact ridiculous: It modifies the input array, and for funsies, makes a copy and then returns the copy, which makes very little sense, and is a mismatch to the method's name. - take the other answer.